# Retrieve Image Attachments Getting Post Thumbnail Image First

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments, get-posts

I have written a funtion to get post  image attachments, is there any way of ordering these images such that the first is always the post_thumbnail?

Code below

Thanks

John

```
function oliver_single_gallery_thumbs() {

global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,          // For the current post
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',       // Get all post attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',            // Only grab images
    'order'          => 'ASC',              // List in ascending order
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',       // List them in their menu order
    'numberposts'    => -1,                 // Show all attachments
    'post_status'    => null,               // For any post status
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) { 
        $count = 0;
        $the_thumbs = '<ul id="single-thumbs">';
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $ze_count = $count+1;
            $the_thumbs .= '<li id="single-thumb-'.$ze_count.'">';
                if ($count==0) {
                    $thumb_attr = array(
                        'class' => "image-radius selected",
                    );
                } else {
                    $thumb_attr = array(
                        'class' => "image-radius",
                    );
                }
                $the_thumbs .= wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'single-thumb', false, $thumb_attr);
            $the_thumbs .= '</li>'."\n";
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
        $the_thumbs .= '</ul>';
    }
    echo $the_thumbs;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, exclude the featured image (= post thumbnail) from the query, then set up the posts array as combination of the featured image and the other images.

Put this directly below `$args = ...` and above `$attachments = ...`:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $args['exclude'] = $featured_image;
    $attachments = array(get_post($featured_image)) + get_posts($args);
} else
```